# Output is printing something weird

Tags: python

I am trying to convert a CSV file to JSON. When I type in my code, it is functioning fine but I am getting all these random letters:\u00ef\u00bb\u00bf. Is this supposed to be happening or do I need to check the file?

Comment: Remove encoding='utf-8' in open('file.csv', 'w', encoding='utf-8') should fix it.

Comment: If you don't present your code, we can't tell what is supposed to be happening because we don't know what the code is trying to do. You are asking us to imagine what you have written and then suggest where the problem in it might be.

Comment: Please, check [ask].

Answer (score 0):

In `json.dump`, add a named parameter `ensure_ascii=False`.

Comment: import csv
import json
data = open(r"C:\Users\nagas\OneDrive\Documents/Test_2.csv").readlines()
print(json.dumps(list(csv.reader(data))))

That is my code. Sry for not giving my code

Comment: No worries. But it's better if you include it in the question itself (click on
"Edit" under your question), because then you can nicely format it, as described
[here](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help), to separate it from your
text. Hint: indent the code with four spaces.